# Comparing all table data of two different keyspaces (Database: Cassandra) with java code

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

1)I have to compare data from tables from 2 different keyspace of cassandra.
The data is huge in table.
How to make connection and compare each rows.
2)I have to write a script which will automatically run on every EOD and compare data of both the schemas(Java)

Excel export and comparison will work or should I have to use apache spark?
Kindly suggest the ways or any sample program if anybody has tried this.

Output should give us the rows which do not match.

Comment: You say that the data is huge, so excel probably would not be a scalable solution. Spark seems to be an effective/only option given your requirement.

Comment: if data is not huge,its about 20K records to compare.
Then what can be the solution?

Comment: Well, if the data is not too big, one way you can compare is to write a cron job that would run `COPY` command (ref: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html) to extract your data to a CSV every 24 hrs and write a program/script that would read this CSV file and verify if the data exists in your other keyspace.